# How to get map to show only desired portion

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, openstreetmap

Say that I have this code (which is modified from [OpenStreetMaps autoplot error in RStudio Server and Shiny Server in R4.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62205981/openstreetmaps-autoplot-error-in-rstudio-server-and-shiny-server-in-r4-0-0)):

```
library(maps)
library(OpenStreetMap)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
mp <- openmap(c(33,-95), c(43,-73),4,'stamen-watercolor')
states_map <- map_data("state")
states_map_merc <- as.data.frame(projectMercator(states_map$lat,states_map$long))
states_map_merc$group <- states_map$group
counties_map <- map_data("county")
counties_map_merc <- as.data.frame(projectMercator(counties_map$lat,counties_map$long))
counties_map_merc$group <- counties_map$group
OpenStreetMap::autoplot.OpenStreetMap(mp,expand=FALSE) + 
    geom_polygon(data=states_map_merc, aes(x=x,y=y,group=group), fill="black",colour="white",alpha=0, size=.5) + 
    geom_polygon(data=counties_map_merc, aes(x=x,y=y,group=group), fill="black",colour="white",alpha=0, size=.1)
```

How can I only get it to make the colored portion of the graph? In other words, only the portion as defined in the `openmap` command.

It currently looks like:

[image]

Also, what do these warning messages mean? Are they anything to worry about?

```
Warning messages:
1: In showSRID(uprojargs, format = "PROJ", multiline = "NO", prefer_proj = prefer_proj) :
  Discarded ellps WGS 84 in Proj4 definition: +proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +k=1 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs +type=crs
2: In showSRID(uprojargs, format = "PROJ", multiline = "NO", prefer_proj = prefer_proj) :
  Discarded datum World Geodetic System 1984 in Proj4 definition
```

Comment: I hope you can get other input on this...but one simple idea is to subset your state and county map data by your bound coordinates c(33, -95) and c(43, -73). For example, use `subset(states_map, lat > 33 & lat < 43 & long > -95 & long < -73)` with `projectMercator` arguments instead of the full `states_map` data, and do the same with `counties_map` too. Then, only longitudes and latitudes within your region of interest will be included (or whatever you decide as limits)...

Comment: In addition, [this vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgdal/vignettes/PROJ6_GDAL3.html) may offer some thoughts regarding the warnings. This appears to be related to changes in proj library, also see [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/372692/how-should-i-handle-crs-properly-after-the-major-change-in-proj-library). The `projectMercator` function in OpenStreetMap is using `proj4string` and may be responsible for the warnings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I obtained the bbox information from the mp object as follows:

```
> mp[["bbox"]][["p1"]]
[1] -10575352   5311972
> mp[["bbox"]][["p2"]]
[1] -8126323  3895304
```

And then modified the limits of the ggplot as follows:

```
OpenStreetMap::autoplot.OpenStreetMap(mp,expand=FALSE) + 
  geom_polygon(data=states_map_merc, aes(x=x,y=y,group=group), fill="black",colour="white",alpha=0, size=.5) + 
  geom_polygon(data=counties_map_merc, aes(x=x,y=y,group=group), fill="black",colour="white",alpha=0, size=.1)+
  
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0), limits = c(-10575352 ,-8126323))+
  
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0), limits = c(3895304, 5311972))
```

The last two lines define the expansion and limits of axes. More information are [here](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_continuous.html)

EDIT:[image: The final plot]