# Remove roads from OpenStreeMap map

Tags: r, dictionary, ggplot2, openstreetmap

Is it possible to not have roads displayed in an `OpenStreetMap`? For instance, using this code (see [How to get map to show only desired portion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67641976/how-to-get-map-to-show-only-desired-portion?noredirect=1#comment119602984_67641976)):

```
library(maps)
library(OpenStreetMap)
mp <- openmap(c(33,-95), c(43,-73),zoom=8,'stamen-watercolor')
states_map <- map_data("state") %>% filter(lat > 33 & lat < 43 & long > -95 & long < -73)
states_map_merc <- as.data.frame(projectMercator(states_map$lat,states_map$long))
states_map_merc$group <- states_map$group
counties_map <- map_data("county") %>% filter(lat > 33 & lat < 43 & long > -95 & long < -73)
counties_map_merc <- as.data.frame(projectMercator(counties_map$lat,counties_map$long))
counties_map_merc$group <- counties_map$group
OpenStreetMap::autoplot.OpenStreetMap(mp,expand=FALSE) + 
    geom_polygon(data=states_map_merc, aes(x=x,y=y,group=group), fill="black",colour="white",alpha=0, size=.7) + 
    geom_polygon(data=counties_map_merc, aes(x=x,y=y,group=group), fill="black",colour="white",alpha=0, size=.2)
```

...is it possible to get rid of the roads on the map while *not* modifying the zoom level?

[image]

Comment: Hey! This sounds like a tough process! When I go through the openstreetmap object in R. There is no information about streets (just colours in Hex code). You could check the colours that represent the street and replace with non-street colour. [check this:](https://imagecolorpicker.com/en)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this doesn't seem to be possible, as it is a feature of the map type you chose (`stamen-watercolor`).

If you don't want the roads displayed, you will need to choose another map type, for example:

`mp <- openmap(c(33,-95), c(43,-73), zoom=8, type = 'bing')`

[image: Bing Map type]

Here are [some examples](http://blog.fellstat.com/?p=356) of different map types that may be helpful for you.